# I want to get capital alphabet without pressing caps lock on and shift key

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

If I give an alphabet value in `jtextfield` without using <kbd>caps lock</kbd> on, or <kbd>shift</kbd> key, it should give capital alphabet value. I don't know how to overcome in this problem. Give me a code to work out this question.

Comment: You problem is that jtextfield capitalizes the input or that you want to capitalize it, regardless of caps lock and shift?

Comment: I want that jtextfield should capitalize an input.

Comment: I don't see a question. Nor do I see an attempt by you to actually try on your own. Hint: This is fairly trivial to figure out (and if it's homework you should really do it on your own).

Comment: String value=text1.getText();
String str=value.toUpperCase();text1.setText(str);

Comment: This is the code i used, but i dont want to use this code. because the input conversion is visible in the jtextfield. so i want to use another code.

Comment: So you don't want the jtextfield to show the capitalized input?

Comment: yes, It should give a capital alphabet, when i am pressing the key a. It not support to convert after pressed.

Answer (score 6):

> Customized fields can easily be created by extending the model and changing the default model provided. For example, the following piece of code will create a field that holds only upper case characters. It will work even if text is pasted into from the clipboard or it is altered via programmatic changes.

```
 public class UpperCaseField extends JTextField {

     public UpperCaseField(int cols) {
         super(cols);
     }

     protected Document createDefaultModel() {
         return new UpperCaseDocument();
     }

     static class UpperCaseDocument extends PlainDocument {

         public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
             throws BadLocationException {

             if (str == null) {
                 return;
             }
             char[] upper = str.toCharArray();
             for (int i = 0; i < upper.length; i++) {
                 upper[i] = Character.toUpperCase(upper[i]);
             }
             super.insertString(offs, new String(upper), a);
         }
     }
 }
```

Courtesy : [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Comment: why do you have UpperCaseDocument as a static inner class and then instantiate it?

Comment: @Efthymis you don't have to - but if you do it's re-usable without an instance of the enclosing class

Answer (score 3):

Define a `DocumentFilter` and assign to the `JTextFiled`'s `Document` or just extend `PlainDocument` used in `JTextField` and override `insertString()` method. convert to uppser case the String parameter and pass to `super.insertString()`

Comment: +1, a DocumentFilter is preferred over using a custom Document because the filter can be reused on for other text components as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the on key up event for text field and reset text to toUpperCase.

```
textField.setText(textField.getText().toUpperCase());
```

A better way is shown here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Comment: This wont work. The person that asked the Question wanted a JTextField that when he types any alphabet even without capsLock on the field still takes caps

Comment: I think you are missing the point. When you get the event of a key press, on key up - the text is reset. So regardless of CAPSLOCK it will always set to UPPER CASE.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
jtextfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
   keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText().toUpperCase());
   }

});
```

Comment: jtextfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
   keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText().toUpperCase());
   }

});

Comment: this code is converting the key as uppercase after i released a key. so i want to convert while i pressing, will use key down.

Comment: @StanislavL I agree, but the question was reffering to typing input. To accomodate all cases you should pass an action for a property change with actionPropertyChanged().

Comment: I tried, the keypressed() is converting after i pressed a second key.

Comment: @arasicode You could try keyTyped event, but it will not work in non unicode characters.

Comment: don't use keyListeners, ever - especially not for modifying text while typing

Comment: @kleopatra could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: don't know what there is to elaborate - it's simply wrong to use keyListeners if you want to modify input text (for one reason see @StanislavL comment) The general rule is to _always_ use the highest abstraction available - on that scale keyListeners are under-earthly ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra don't get me wrong, I just want to fix whatever I am doing wrong and learn on the process.

Comment: May i know, how to modify a jtextfield while typing without using keylistener.

Comment: StanislavL gave the answer 5 hours ago.